# how to do a url_for in flask restful using blueprints?

Tags: python, flask

code:

blueprint:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restful import Api
################################

### Local Imports ###

################################


profile_api = Blueprint('profile_api', __name__)
api = Api(profile_api)
from .views import *
```

views:

```
class ShowProfPic(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return "hey"

api.add_resource(ShowProfPic, '/get profile picture/',endpoint="showpic")
```

how do we do a `url_for` with `flask_restful?`
because when I do.

`url_for('showpic')` it's a routing error
and when I do `url_for('api.ShowProfPic')`
it's also still a routing error

Comment: @Celeo this through the use of blueprints is it still a duplicate?

Answer (score 6):

I've got the answer.

Apparently when working with `blueprints`

the way to access `flask_restful's` `url_for` is

`url_for('blueprint_name.endpoint)`

meaning an endpoint has to be specified on the resource

so using the example above:

```
profile_api = Blueprint('profile_api', __name__)
api = Api(profile_api)
from .views import *


class ShowProfPic(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return "hey"

api.add_resource(ShowProfPic, '/get profile picture/',endpoint="showpic")
```

to reference the `ShowProfPic` class and get it's `endpoint`
it's `url_for('blueprint_name.endpoint')`
so that's `url_for(profile_api.showpic)`